# Tackling polymorphic behaviour in a DDD

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

There is a scenario in which a `Credential` class contains a digital `Proof`. Each type of `Credential` can support multiple different types of `Proof` like `JWSProof` or a simple `RSASignatureProof` derived from the same base class (`Proof`) and specify the different behaviour to do the verification.

Suppose that a client sends the a credential containing a JWS proof, after receiving the data, the controller endpoint maps it to a `Credential` (that could eventually be stored afterwards) and somehow recognizes the proof type contained inside it. Its task is to verify it before processing (or saving it) so it should use the logic implemented in the related class (`JWSProof` in this case) by constructing it using a factory after collecting the cryptographic material necessary to do the verification.

So my question is: do you think this is the correct approach? I feel like the `JWSProof` is somehow useless as its logic could easily become a static function. How would you model this case and how many repositories are necessary to store all of these type of objects/classes?

Comment: Does each type of *Proof* operate on the same kind of data (i.e. same data structure) and only have different algorithms to perform? Or is the input data for the verification logic of the Proof also different for each type of Proof?

Comment: I think it is easier to make suggestions if you could provide some sample code.

Comment: Operate on the same kind of data (a string after all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your explanation (see comments to question) that each type of *Proof* operates on the same kind of input data in terms of data structure (in your case simply a string) we are only concerned with different proof verification logic.

This sounds like *Proof* is more like behaviour only (logic) and does not represent data in your domain model. This is why I would suggest to handle this via the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This means there is a strategy implementation containing the verification logic for each different kind of proof. I would not suggest to use static methods because this makes testing and maintenance difficult.

You could implement a Credential factory that creates the corresponding Credential aggregate and already injects the specific ***proof strategy*** based on the *proof type*.

If this solution is feasible for your problem you do not even require different Credential class types due to different proof logic. Because when ***storing*** the ***Credential aggregate*** it always has the same structure and only the proof type's value (e.g. create a custom ProofType value object for strong typing) differs.

Comment: I need to derive other `Credential` types in order to bind the proof type to it otherwise when receiving a data from an endpoint I don't know how to choose the correct strategy

Comment: That's fine, I just meant no need for a Proof Validation entity because it's just verification logic. Still you could simply store a proof type and create the Credential instance with the corresponding strategy based on that. Or you already call the Credential factory where handling the API.

Comment: What if I subclass a `ProofStrategy` class to implement the different verification types but each one needs different runtime arguments to execute?

Comment: That's the advantage of the strategy pattern. As the base strategy is just an interface the specific Implementations of that interface can take whatever parameters you want in the constructor. And this construction can be orchestrated by the factory. So you can still have different data for each strategy at runtime and still don't need to put this data in your persistent domain model representation if this data is only needed during the execution of the verification.

Comment: I'm not talking about the parameters of the constructor because the verification process needs arguments that can be retrieved after the Credential has been received. The verification is done on another end that is not the one responsible for creating the Credential.

Answer (score 0):

For pure computational logic that doesn't need to change (and I'd suggest that a proof algorithm is such a thing: it likely has no state from verification to verification), source code (e.g. a static function) is the correct repository.

Your `ProofRepository` would then fundamentally just be a map from an identifier for a proof (e.g. a string like `"JWSProof"`) to a static function (different languages will make this easier or harder to model, especially if the proof implementations need to take different arguments).

You might by the same token have a repository for cryptographic materials needed by particular proofs.

Comment: So the polymorphic behaviour needed for the verification algorithm is just recognizing the proof type and invoking the corresponding function by mapping it? In this case I cannot take any advantage from a polymorphic implementation

Comment: Nothing in this precludes a polymorphic implementation.  But for resolution of which to use, if `Proof` is an important enough thing in your domain to model separately, the features in your language which support polymorphic dispatch aren't going to be usable because to use them, you would still have to resolve an opaque identifier (e.g. "JWSProof") to the moral equivalent of a (potentially partially-applied closure)

Comment: The thing is that `Proof` and the containing `Credential` are sent and retrieved on the net so they are serialized/deserialized

Comment: So the question is how to serialize/deserialize the proof?  That's completely orthogonal to the repository question.

Comment: If you're talking about a serializable definition of an algorithm, you're talking about a program: you're on the expressway to defining your own programming language (maybe not a turing-complete language).

Comment: Knowing that `Credential` could potentially contain any type of `Proof` and that `Credential` should be serialize (so sent) on the internet, how would you deserialize the contained `Proof` on the other end? My guess is that you need a factory method that should be invoked by inspecting the type contained in the `Proof`. That's why I'm using a DDD because the logic to handle that specific type of `Proof` is contained in the related subclass.

Comment: Are there a finite number of `Proof`s possible?

Comment: If there are, then all you need is a map (or dictionary, or hash, or whatever: programming languages and cultures use a lot of different terminology for the same concept) from key to `Proof` and you transmit the key.

Comment: Inside a `Credential` there's only one `Proof` at time but currently I have like three types of `Proof` and this number is subject to change over time

Comment: Then a map is all you need

Comment: Your choice is basically between defining a programming language for representing the proof process in a serializable way and then you can exchange arbitrary proofs directly over the wire and save the programs in a repository, or you hardwire them into your source but with a dynamic lookup to dispatch them

Comment: Either of those is valid: one is a lot less effort than the other.

Comment: I don't need to serialize the proof processing algorithm, what I need is to correctly choosing the right algorithm to process (verification) that type of proof on the other end

Comment: Then all you need to do is serialize an identifier for an algorithm and what is effectively a map of identifiers to functions implementing that algorithm.